# Batch: Find all files in folder that start with

Tags: regex, batch-file

I'm new to batch scripting and trying to find a way to iterate through all files in a folder and print the names of all files who start with Test_ and end with .py (i.e python files)

I'm stuck here:

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%f | findstr /r "^Test_[.]*\.py$"
)
pause
```

But this doesn't echo anything to screen.
Can you help?

Thanks,

Noam

Comment: Try `"^Test_.*\.py$"`

Comment: Why not use the file mask with the `FOR` command? `for /r %%f in (Test_*.py) do (`

Answer (score 1):

Try "Dir /b "Test_*.py""

Also you can do "Dir /b "C:\path\Test_*.py""

Comment: Might want to explain the `/S` switch as well because their original code is using `FOR /R` which is recursive as well.

Comment: Aha yes add /s after the /b to go to all sub folders

Answer (score 1):

You may find the `Where` command useful:

```dos
Where/R . "Test_?*.py"
```

Comment: if I already know there will be only exactly one match, is it possible to directly asign the result to a variable or would I still need a `for` loop? I'm aksing because I once had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450531/batch-write-output-of-dir-to-a-variable) but didn't know `Where` exists and I think it would simplify my code a lot

Comment: I'm sorry @derHugo, I'm not in the habit of providing free support to members based upon a comment made to a 20 month old, not accepted answer.